# GNU GRUB: Suddenly prompts for unknown username and password?

Tags: boot, server, grub2, login, password

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 on a vm and after a power surge I now get prompted with a username and password screen when trying to boot with GNU GRUB.

This is how the GNU GRUB splash screen looks like:
[image: GNU GRUB SPLASH SCREEN]

When clicking 'enter', 'e', or 'c' this is what comes up:

[image: GNU GRUB USERNAME PROMPT]

After entering a username and password (just blank this time) I get this:
[image: What happens after I try to enter a username and password]

After clicking any key it returns back to the main splash screen.

I have tested any of my own username/password combinations, and also some common ones like, root:root, but nothing works.

I am curious how GNU GRUB suddenly prompts me with a password after a power surge, but most importantly I would like to undo the username and password requirement.

As displayed in the first screenshot I am using GNU GRUB versoin 2.02 beta2-36ubuntu3.17

Any ideas?

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you try 'ubuntu' as both the username and password? This is usually the default I think

Comment: @Hugo I just tried it, and it doesn't work.

Comment: @Mini Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Champ It being 4 years ago I don't really remember. I believe I might have given up and did a fresh install.