# after power outage: grub asks for (unknown) user name and password

Tags: boot, grub2, password

We have an Ubuntu computer that perfectly worked until a power outage.
All of a sudden, the computer now boots into GRUB, giving the option to start Ubuntu or Ubuntu in safe mode.

However, when choosing either of these options it asks for a username and then a password. Using our Ubuntu account is not working.
For a picture, see here: [image: here]

So we are stuck on this screen and can not boot into Ubuntu anymore.

Is there a standard GRUB password that we should use? Or what else can we do in this situation to boot into Ubuntu again?

Thank you!

P.S.:
I think we have exactly the same problem as described here:
[GNU GRUB: Suddenly prompts for unknown username and password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018860/gnu-grub-suddenly-prompts-for-unknown-username-and-password)
(unfortunately no answer there)

Comment: Could you please add a photo of the screen you stuck in so that we can see what you're talking about?

Comment: I am currently not in front of the computer but I added an earlier photo that at least shows the login prompt

Comment: This is not a grub screen, that's from your Bios/UEFI.

Comment: Yes, actually last time I was in front of the computer it exactly looked like the screenshots in the other post that I just linked, which is a grub screen, I suppose?

Comment: No, the picture you show is not a grub screen, it's a Bios screen. This is not a grub problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try logging in as root and then go through the users that way? Just type in
$cat /etc/passwd to view users then
$passwd  to change the password?

My Debian Stretch boots into GRUB as default. I just type "exit" (without inverted commas) and it continues on to Debian Desktop.

Comment: Sorry the website changed my answer. Type $passwd username of user to change the users password.

Comment: so the username + pw that used to be the root is simply not working. So I have no way to get past that username + pw screen, except there is some kind of standard username and pw combination that I am not aware of (?)

Comment: Well I don't need a grub password. The screen you posted doesn't look like grub. When does this screen show? What does it go through? Have you tried getting on to the system settings menu by pressing F2 or F8 a number of times when the computer starts?